# ¿ Cómo sacar la información de un item de listView, lo que lleva dentro sin la posicion?

Tags: java, android

Es decir, tengo esto :

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                       //Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                       // Realiza lo que deseas, al recibir clic en el elemento de tu listView determinado por su posicion.


                            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "AndroidSolved");
                            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " ¿ Puedes superarme ? Acabo de hacer estos clicks:"+arg0.getItemAtPosition(position));
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Pero el `+arg0.getItemAtPosition(position)` me saca además de la información que quiero LA POSICION del item delante, y no quiero... ¿ cómo hago para sacar la información sin la posición?

Comment: Hola Rf Mvs, Te refieres al texto del elemento?

Comment: Sí, al texto de ese item

Comment: ok estabas usando los elementos AdapterView<?> , debes obtener únicamente el elemento en la posición: (String) lista.getItemAtPosition(position) , agregue una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas obtener el texto simplemente obtén el contenido del elemento dentro del `ListView`:

```
String elementodeLista = (String) lista.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

y este valor lo usas en tu Intent:

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " ¿ Puedes superarme ? Acabo de hacer estos clicks:"+ elementodeLista);
```

o también:

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " ¿ Puedes superarme ? Acabo de hacer estos clicks:"+ (String) lista.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

Comment: Elena, eso que me has pasado me hace lo mismo que arg0.getItem... Me devuelve la posición del elemento y el texto y yo solo quiero el texto.. :S

Comment: es decir, imagina que tengo guardado "casa" en la 3a posicion, eso que me has pasado me devuelve: 3 casa y yo solo quiero que me devuelva "casa"

Comment: voy a hacer una cosa, creo que la culpa es mia, porque tengo puesto un numero delante , gracias!

Comment: únicamente debes usar (String) lista.getItemAtPosition(position) y no necesitas todos los datos del AdapterView! =)